# How can I print lines that match a pattern in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Assuming `file.txt` has just one sentence per line  as follows:

```
John Depp is a great guy.  
He is very inteligent.  
He can do anything.  
Come and meet John Depp.
```

The Perl code is as follows:-

```
open ( FILE, "file.txt" ) || die "can't open file!";
@lines = <FILE>;
close (FILE);
$string = "John Depp";
foreach $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ $string) { print "$line"; }
}
```

The output is going to be first and fourth line.

I want to make it working for  the file having random line breaks rather than one English sentence per line. I mean it should also work for the following:-

```
John Depp is a great guy. He is very intelligent. He can do anything. Come and meet John Depp.
```

The output should be first and fourth sentences.

Any ideas please?

Comment: One potential problem which I only recently learned I'd been doing wrong myself: when you do a die statement, it should be "or die" not "|| die", because they actually have different precedence. It will work in this case, because there's only one statement and it can't be grouped with anything else. But you should just use "or die" everywhere anyway.

Comment: @crimson In this case, the OP is fine because of the parentheses used in the `open` call. A more serious issue is the completely unnecessary slurping of the file. Also, the `die` message should include the name of the file and the error message `$!`. In addition, using lexical filehandles and the three-argument form of `open` would make the code in line with what is considered best practice.

Comment: You are right of course. I didn't really look at most of the code, I just glanced at it and thought I'd throw that in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809469/how-do-i-read-paragraphs-at-a-time-with-perl

Answer (score 3):

First, note that the name of the famous actor is [Johnny Depp](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000136/).

Second, figuring out what is a sentence and what is not is tricky. I am going to cheat and use [Lingua::Sentence](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Lingua::Sentence):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Lingua::Sentence;

my $splitter = Lingua::Sentence->new('en');

while ( my $text = <DATA> ) {
    for my $sentence ( split /\n/, $splitter->split($text) ) {
        print $sentence, "\n" if $sentence =~ /John Depp/;
    }
}

__DATA__
John Depp is a great guy.
He is very intelligent.
He can do anything.
Come and meet John Depp.
John Depp is a great guy. He is very intelligent. He can do anything. Come and meet John Depp.
```

Output:

```
John Depp is a great guy.
Come and meet John Depp.
John Depp is a great guy.
Come and meet John Depp.
```

Answer (score 2):

More simple: if you assume "sentences" are separated by dots, then you can use that as field separator:

```
 $/ = '.';
 while(<>) {
        print if (/John Depp/i);
 }
```

Comment: That works for the simple example but fails if one of the sentences refers to *Mr.* John Depp.

Comment: Of course. But, what do you expect the ideal perl code to output given this input?

"John Depp is a great guy. He can do anything. Come and meet Mr. John Depp. He is very intelligent. " ?

Do you expect perl to "know" that "Come and meet Mr. John Depp." is one sentence ? How?

Comment: That is, I was assumming that the author were looking just for a regex  solution (tagged 'regex') in which case one must do some simple assumption about how sentences are delimited. If this is not enough (in real english it is not), one must resort to some library who knows the intrincancies of english written language - as you have pointed out (Lingua::Sentence)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your content in a string:

```
my $content = "John Depp is a great guy.  
He is very intelligent.  
He can do anything.  
Come and meet John Depp.";

my @arr = $content =~ /.*John Depp.*/mg;
foreach my $a (@arr) {
    print "$a\n";
}
```

Result:

> John Depp is a great guy.
> Come and meet John Depp.

You can modify the regex if you want to extract only the interesting part, like:

```
my @arr = $content =~ /is (\w+? ?\w+ \w+)./mg;
```

Result:

> a great guy
>
> very intelligent

Answer (score 0):

one way

```
while(<>){
 if (/John Depp/i){
   @s = split /\s*\.\s*/;
   foreach my $line (@s){
      @f=split /\s*\.\s*/ , $line;
      foreach my $found (@f){
        if ($found =~/John Depp/i) {
           print $found."\n";
        }
      }
   }
 }
}
```

output

```
$ cat file
John Depp is a great guy.
He is very inteligent.
He can do anything.
Come and meet John Depp.
John Depp is a great guy. He is very inteligent. He can do anything. Come and meet John Depp.

$ perl perl.pl file
John Depp is a great guy
Come and meet John Depp
John Depp is a great guy
Come and meet John Depp
```

Comment: What if you have `John\nDepp eats with scissors.` in your file?

Comment: there are a lot of what if's right? don't ask me, ask the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Default variables can get clobbered if one isn't careful. So naming everything is a good idea.

This should get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $targetString = "John Depp";

while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp($line);
    my @elements = split("\\.", $line);
    foreach my $element (@elements) {
        if ($element =~ m/$targetString/is) {
            print trim($element).".\n";
        }
    }
}

sub trim {
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ depp.pl < file
John Depp is a great guy.
Come and meet John Depp.
John Depp is a great guy.
Come and meet John Depp.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your original code rather than specifically answering your question. It is generally a bad idea to read a whole file into memory unless you have to. You can process a file line by line as

```
open ( FILE, "file.txt" ) || die "can't open file!";
$string = "John Depp";
while (<FILE>) {
   if (/$string/) { print }
}
```