# Perl read text in paragraph and patternmatch

Tags: perl

I have an index file, which keeps an index of each object separated by a blank line. Now, I have to search for a keyword on each object, and if present, dump to another file, instead of rebuilding the entire index from the scratch. The piece of code

```
###@files is an array that contains the list of packages in the index
 open("FH", $indexfile) or die ;
 my @linearray = <FH>;
 close ("FH");

 open (NFH, '>', "$tmpfile") or die "cannot create";
     foreach my $pattern (@files)
{
    if (my @matches = grep /$pattern/, @linearray) {
        print NFH "@matches";
    } else {
        push @newpkgs,$pattern;
    }
}
close (NFH);
```

But this is not working as expected. How can I get a paragraph as an element in an array?

Comment: Try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809469/how-do-i-read-paragraphs-at-a-time-with-perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify $/

```
my @linearray;
    {
    open("FH", $indexfile) or die ;
    local $/ = '';
    @linearray = <FH>;
    close ("FH");
    print Dumper @linearray;
    }
```

This will give you the required output.

I used the braces {} to limit the scope of Field Record Separator modification till the objects are read to the array. You can extend it according to your requirement.

Comment: You have to declare `my @linearray` outside of the block else it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. My bad. my @linearray has to be declared outside the block.